# Relative Pronoun "Which" in a defining clause

Tags: grammar, word-usage, relative-pronouns

I've seen topics regarding this subject and people said "which" can be used in a defining clause - which is very odd to me. That's why I'm asking whether this usage is okay.

Examples:

> The soda *which* I drank had a strong smell. (Instead of saying: "The soda *that* I drank [...]")
>
> The subject *which* I wrote about is of such importance. (Instead of saying "The subject *that* I wrote about [...])

Comment: You can use "which" or "that"; it's a free choice.

Comment: Or neither of them.

Comment: (What @WeatherVane is saying is that you could drop the word *which* in both examples, and it'd be fine.) I do feel like the *which* in the second sentence "sounds weird". But it's not actually ungrammatical.

Comment: The "which", which can indicate without specifying, introduces both defining and non-defining elements.  The "that" that introduces a modifier doesn't work with non-defining elements because it's referent, even when unknown, is specific.

Answer (score 2):

*The soda (that / which) I drank had a strong smell*.

It's a free choice between a *wh* relative, a *that* relative and a bare relative.

Many speakers would prefer a non-*wh* relative, but it is only a preference; a *wh* relative here is perfectly grammatical here.